Winform VB.net Datagridviewtextboxcell selectionstart and selection length
I Have a question about a winform:
I need the selection start and length of textboxcell.
As it is now i always get the start and length of a previous edit (eg. the values are one edit behind the latest edit).
Private Sub oParams_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles oParams.EditingControlShowing

    If TypeOf e.Control Is DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl Then
        Dim tbec As DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl = CType(e.Control, DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl)
        Dim cellText As String = tbec.Text

        selCellSt = tbec.SelectionStart
        selCellLen = tbec.SelectionLength
        'MsgBox("start:  " & tbec.SelectionStart & vbNewLine & "Length:  " & tbec.SelectionLength)
    End If


End Sub

When the button is pressed i use this:
Private Sub oParams_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles oParams.CellContentClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 4 Then
        MsgBox("sel start:  " & selCellSt & vbNewLine & "sel lenght:  " & selCellLen)
    End If

Does anyone have a solution so it gets the values of the latest selection ?
Video as reference to wht i mean:
https://youtu.be/mcKWuyA66aA
thank you in advance

That event is raised before the control is displayed, which is obviously before the user has selected any text in that cell. You're getting values from the previous edit because editing controls are reused if possible and the control hasn't been attached to the new cell yet. You need to handle the appropriate events of that editing control, just as you would for any other TextBox, to get the property values at the appropriate time(s).

You may consider binding your DataGridView to a DataTable and then  work with the data in the DataTable. See this post

Selection of text within the cell only makes sense when the editing control is showing. Trying to get that data on the CellContentClick event doesn't make sense, because the cell content can't be selected and it can't be clicked when there's an editing control showing. What you need to do is handle the EditingControlShowing event, which is raised BEFORE the control is shown, and then handle the appropriate events of that control, e.g.
Private WithEvents editingControl As TextBox

Private Sub DataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.EditingControlShowing
    If DataGridView1.CurrentCellAddress.X = 4 Then
        editingControl = DirectCast(e.Control, TextBox)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEndEdit
    editingControl = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub EditingControl_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles editingControl.Enter
    '...
End Sub

Private Sub EditingControl_Leave(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles editingControl.Leave
    '...
End Sub

Just note that there is no event raised by the TextBox control when the SelectionStart or SelectionLength property changes, so there's no simple way to get live values of those properties. You could handle all the events that might be raised when they change, i.e. those related to mouse and keyboard.
